# Push Docker image in Tar ball to a OpenShift Docker

Tags: docker, jenkins, openshift

I have a jenkins in a standalone Windows 7 server. We have a request to add a build job to build a project, which produce a Docker image in Tar ball format, and push the image into a remote Docker Registry, which resides in OpenShift.

Trying to find a jenkins plugin that can do this. Found that [Docker Common](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Docker+Commons+Plugin) plugin have some command but as i understood it can push the image only from a docker registry to another.

Any guide where i can push the tar ball to a remote registry through a standalone jenkins? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

may be this can be helpful, you can run docker on local windows server, and then load the image tar to local docker then push it to remote repo. Steps are given in this link.

https://docs.openshift.com/container-platform/3.11/install/disconnected_install.html#disconnected-populate-registry

Comment: The thing is we can only produce tar ball on the Jenkins server. There's no local docker available.

Comment: Building OCI (docker) images is possible without docker. Have a look at kaniko, maven jib plugin, and generally google for building image without docker. Now days it is normal.